# How to set the appearance of an annotation border

Tags: c#, itext

I add the PdfTextMarkupAnnotation annotation to the document. I would like the left and right edges of the annotation to be concave. They are convex by default. I tried to use the metod annotation.SetBorder(new PdfArray (new int [] {0, 0, 1})); but it doesn't change the appearance of the annotation border in any way.
I would be grateful for any help.[image]

Comment: Is your image what you want or what you get?

Comment: This is what I have. I want to get an annotation with concave ends.